# Combining glossaries and index?

Tags: macros, glossaries, indexing

I am working on a document where glossary entries are referred to from the index. This works, until I add conditional text, indicating whether a description was added or not. It looks like TeX falls into an unbounded recursion, but I cannot seem to wrap my head around this. Without adding an index entry, this works. Any help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries}

\makeindex

\makeatletter
\def\ifentry#1#2#3{%
    \edef\tmp{#1}%
    \ifx\tmp\@empty%
        #3%
    \else%
        #2%
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

\newglossarystyle{descriptiontest}{%

    \setglossarystyle{indexgroup}

    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{
        \item \textbf{{\glossentryname{##1}}}
        \edef\tmp{\glsentrydesc{##1}}
        \ifentry\tmp{Description: '\tmp'}{No description}

    }
} 

\newglossaryentry{ham}{name={ham}, description={goes with eggs\index{ham}}}     
\newglossaryentry{eggs}{name={eggs}, description=}     

\makeglossaries



\begin{document}

 \glsaddall

 \printglossary[style=descriptiontest]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted out by Nicola Talbot on comp.text.tex:

> The glossaries package comes with conditional commands for testing if
>   a key has been set. \ifglshasdesc not only tests for an empty
>   description but also tests if the description has simply been set to
>   \nopostdesc